# Is there another way to manipulate shareable variables in postman test, without using PM object?

Tags: automated-tests, postman, newman

I have an collection in the Postman with automated E2E tests, and some calls need to share variables. Currently I being using the object `pm` to set the values (`pm.global.set("envName", "envValue")`), but this aproach is not good...
Have a way to handle this variables like an "normal var"?

Comment: why `this aproach is not good`? I don't see a real problem in your question. The script part is a sanbox, to share value between them, it has to save value somewhere else like environment, global, collection through `pm` object.

Comment: because using the `pm` object, we can't access autocomplete and syntax checking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no way to resolve that... to set and get sharable env, the only way is using the `pm` object.

check this question: [Postman - Pass local variable from Pre-request Script into the Body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74531876/postman-pass-local-variable-from-pre-request-script-into-the-body)